# Twilio sometimes responds to SMS or Phone Call resource requests too fast

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql, twilio

**Background**

I have a stateless web application, written in C# and powered by Transact-SQL. There could be n servers running at any given time, so to preserve the state of each phone call/sms message, we're writing call details to database.

**The Problem**

Most of the time this works, as the database is able to write the Call/SMS SID to database before Twilio makes the callback. Sometimes however, we're seeing Twilio callbacks arrive *before* the data has been written to database.

I've watched this happen in real-time in my debug environment, so I'm 100% confident this is what's going on.

**Attempted Solutions**

So our main table that tracks each call/sms is huge, and it's heavily indexed, as a number of processes depend on being able to see quick responses to queries on that table. This has the side effect of slowing down write speed however.

So, what I've done is created a redundant buffer table of all the in-progress calls. Once the appropriate callbacks are made by Twilio, we flag the row for deletion and it gets deleted in a batch (about once per minute).

This strategy has mitigated the problem, however we're sometimes seeing Twilio make the callbacks before that table has been written to as well. Hats off to Twilio for being able to respond to call requests so quickly, but it's really a thorn in my side, as so much of our software depends on those callbacks happening successfully. If the SID isn't written to database by the time the callback arrives, there's no way to relate the call to the database record.

**Off The Table Solutions**

Memory Optimized Tables are off the table unfortunately, as our azure SQL tier is fairly low (we're a non-profit org). I've done some more work to optimize the database, but again, even on our super small buffer table, the data isn't written quickly enough.

**The Question**

So, with the above, I have a few questions:

- Can I retrieve the call/SMS SID before I start the phone call? This way I can await the database write action before starting the call.
- Can I force Twilio to retry the callback later when my server fails to retrieve the SID?

**Code:**

```
private static void MakeCall(Shift_Offer so, Callout callout, testdb2Entities5 db)
        {
            callout.status = CalloutStatus.inprogress;
            db.SaveChanges();
            try
            {
                // CallQueue is a special table for fast write access, 
                //so we can maintain relationship between call and sid before big slow ShiftOffer table has finished writing
                CallQueue callQueueItem = new CallQueue(); 
                callQueueItem.offer_id = so.shift_offer_id;
                callQueueItem.offer_finished = false;           
                var call = CallResource.Create //twilio starts the call when you call create
                            (
                                url: new Uri(TwilioCallBotController.TwilioCalloutScriptURL),
                                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(RCHStringHelpers.formatPhoneNumber(callout.callback_number)),
                                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(RCHStringHelpers.formatPhoneNumber(so.employee_phone_number)),
                                statusCallback: new Uri(TwilioCallBotController.StatusCallbackURL),
                                statusCallbackEvent: new List<string> { "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed" }
                            );
                callQueueItem.twilio_sid = call.Sid; //only after create is called do we have an Sid
                db.CallQueues.Add(callQueueItem); //write SID to buffer table
                db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
                so.offer_timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();               
                if (call.Status != CallResource.StatusEnum.Failed)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(call.Sid.ToString()
                                    + " " + call.StartTime.ToString()
                                    + " " + call.Status.ToString());
                    so.twillio_sid = call.Sid; //now we write the SID to our main call tracking table
                    so.status = call.Status.ToString();
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    callQueueItem.offer_finished = true;
                    so.offer_status = ShiftOfferStatus.Failed;
                    so.status = call.Status.ToString();
                    callout.status = CalloutStatus.inprogressWaitingNext;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Debug.WriteLine(call.Status.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e) //if we run into any problems here, release the lock to prevent stalling
            {
                 //do exception handling stuff here, not relevant to this question
            }
}
```

Comment: How does Twilio get his data from the callback ? It's not from the DB ? (Sorry I don't know a lot about Twilio)

Comment: I think you're going to have to show us your code.  Fundamentally, it seems like you simply need to block while the database write is in flight.

Comment: @JFPicard - Twilio calls back with an SID, which is assigned when the call resource is created. I then relate the specifics of each call to the SID, and return some xml (called twiml) that tells the voip service what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems like a concurent problem. Since you cannot assert when the callback from twilio will be fired (before or after the DB write), you can assume that the call will be before.

Hence, you need a way to notify the callback method if the write to the DB was sucessfull. Like this:

```
      dbWriteFlag = false;
      db.CallQueues.Add(callQueueItem); //write SID to buffer table
      db.SaveChanges();
      dbWriteFlag = true;
```

and the callback method access the flag to know if it was writen.

If you don't have acces to that kind of flag, I can suggest to check if the record is in the DB before doing something and if not, wait and recheck until it's written.

Comment: No way to know if Twilio will make the callback to the same server, so any stateful solution won't work.

But we *do* know that if the callback is happening, that the write operation is at least in-progress. Methinks you're right, to just delay the response and wait for the database to finish writing.